# Cropped hamburger icon on mobile devices

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, mobile-web

While browsing Stack Overflow on my mobile device, I've stumbled upon the cropped hamburger icon to toggle the communities list. However, this is not limited to my phone and seems to be the same for most of the other sites in the Stack Exchange network as well.

I'm not sure if this is intended or not, but compared to the iOS app it doesn't seem to be right. The hamburger icon in the app is not cropped and has lots of space to the left side, so I just wanted to report/discuss it on Meta to let you know.

You can see the cropped hamburger icon (`.icon-hamburger` in CSS) in the screenshot (taken via Chrome Developer Tools) below.

[image: Screenshot of the cropped hamburger icon]

Comment: This bugs me too, but I think it might be by design to signal that the logo part is a menu?

Comment: Yep, mildly weird but by design. This was a pattern on Android at the time the mobile views were built. We’re in the process of removing these mobile views in favor of responsive views, so this top bar will be going away.

Comment: FR: We need to refer to cropped hamburgers as sliders. :D

Comment: @AaronShekey think it fits as answer. Thanks!