# Fix layout of top bar in mobile

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, top-bar

In the mobile version of some pages of Stack Exchange websites, the top bar appears wider than the page; it extends off the left side, but not off the right.

[image: Extra wide top bar screenshot]

Pages where I've specifically noticed this behavior are on the home pages (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com) and on questions themselves.

Pages where I don't see this behavior include `/questions/ask` and the login page.

[image: Screenshot of top bar on /questions/ask]

Requesting the desktop version of the pages fixes this issue, but is hardly desirable.

[image: Screenshot of top bar after requesting the desktop version of the site]

I've tested this behavior in iOS versions of Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Edge, on meta.stackexchange.com and stackoverflow.com.  I'm pretty certain I've seen it on every site I've been to on mobile though.

After a bit of investigation, I think this is a `width` + `left` bug on the icon and would require a `padding` change on the `<a>` that contains it.  That, and/or it's that the pages that aren't broken use the `.left-sidebar-toggle` class instead of `.icon-hamburger`.  It's strange to me that a different top bar component is used in the first place.

<sub>I'm surprised I couldn't find a duplicate to this question, so forgive me if there is one and I just missed it in the first 20 or so questions I looked at.</sub>

Comment: You only see this in the mobile view (toggle it in the footer, not all pages have mobile view), which is supposed to go away at some point in the near future. It's doubtful this will be fixed, especially since it's always been like that and works well enough

Comment: Yes!  Thanks.  Feel free to mark this as a dupe.

Comment: This ***was*** fixed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329838/282094 and previously going to be fixed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306123/282094  - so a "new ask" isn't a duplicate of an [old unanswered report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288754/cropped-hamburger-icon-on-mobile-devices) when there's a newer one than that claiming it was fixed, that is also not recent. - Fair to ask again, might be declined since mobile views are being deprecated by year's end (maybe a bit later).